# How to manually change BPM of part of clip in Ableton

Tags: ableton, ableton-live, sync

How do you take from point A to point B inside a warped clip, and change it's BPM from 120 to 140?

Reason is I need to sync a video track with a audio track, video has music with not a constant BPM. I don't want to slice the track because it puts a micro second black screen between videos.

I tried playing around with the warp markers and inserting markers but it only works when there is only one yellow marker at the beginning of the track and then I select it and the BPM slot becomes editable. If somehow the track has more than 1 yellow marker I can't do anything, and as to how to change the BPM between point A and B, I am clueless.

Answer (score 1):

The traditional way to change the tempo (bpm) for just a part of a clip in Ableton Live is to create a warp marker at the beginning and end of the section of your clip that you want to stretch, since you know where it should begin and end. Stretch the markers out so that it takes the appropriate amount of time. This process is called "warping" and it's worth taking some time to get familiar with it, as it's quite powerful.

The advantage to doing it this way is that you don't actually have to know the intended tempo - Live will figure it out based on your endpoints.